# What is the type of this column?

Tags: sql-server

In sql server, when I create a column like:

```
select *, '1' as test
```

what is the type of this new column i.e 1 ?

Just one more question, can I reference this column on other table?

Comment: It may depend on RDBMS, the most probable is `Char(1)`

Comment: ANSI/ISO SQL: "The declared type of a <character string literal> is fixed-length character string. The length of a <character
string literal> is the number of <character representation>s that it contains." i.e. `character(1)` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server, you can answer such questions easily using [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx):

```
exec sp_describe_first_result_set N'select *, ''1'' as test from sys.objects'
```

Produces a result set, the last row of which indicates that the `test` column in that result set is of type `varchar(1)`. (Other results in this case, pulling the other columns from the `sys.objects` table make it clear that this procedure is capable of describing columns as non-`var` `char(2)` or `nvarchar(128)`, so it's not just a display issue)

Answer (score 0):

This column has char(1) type and yes u can use this column in joins or other manipulation etc as well.

because its value is a string within ' ' If you want it to be an integer. you can do the following:

```
 select *, Cast(1 as INT) as test FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - that may be the more sensible result but it's not what e.g. SQL Server produces.